# bash: removing filles matching different glob patterns

Tags: bash

I am writting short bash routine aimed at finding of filles located in the same (home) folder and matching three different glob patterns in their names:

```
# home folder
home="$PWD"
# remove all unused filles from $HOME >> to be fixed
# delete all filles contained "results_" namming pattern
    find "${home}" -type f -iname results_* -delete
# delete all png images
    find "${home}" -type f -iname *.png -delete
# delete all filles having slash (#) at the begining of the names
    find "${home}" -type f -iname '#*' -delete
```

while executing this secuence of commands I got the following message in the terminal

```
find: results_bench: unknown primary or operator
```

that indicates that in HOME there is also a folder matching "results_*" pattern. How I could apply my routine only on filles (ignoring folders)? Is it possible to combine all three find expressions in one line command?

Comment: Put a backslash in front of the glob pattern. Or (double) quote the filename. E.g. `results-\*` or `"*.png"`.

Comment: Note that `#` is called a hash, or pound sign; not slash.

Comment: Thank you! I think it works now (however it slow down script) would it be a good idea additionally to put this sequence of find commands inside IF conditions (if these three groups of filles exist in home) ?

Comment: `find "$home" '(' -iname 'results_*' -o -iname '*.png' -o -iname '#*' ')' -type f -delete` would be faster.

Comment: OK, thank you! Do I need any special escaping of glob pattern in the case of pattern with hash ( according to the previous comment) ?

Comment: .. for instance what would be difference between -iname '*.png' and -iname *.png (without quotes)?